# Multi-line user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-input

I want to be able to accept multi-line user input. The problem is that with my program the user can't just use <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to do it.

I want them to be able to paste in several paragraphs for translation and when it detects a new line it automatically takes it as an enter and cuts off the input. I am using `raw_input`, not `input`.

Does anyone know a way to overcome this, so it can accept pasted text with multiple lines without assuming it is the end of the input?

Answer (score 1):

You can repeatedly ask for `raw_input()` in a loop and concatenate the lines until you hit some input that signalizes the end. A very common one would be an empty line:

```
allLines = []
print('Insert the text:')
while True:
    line = raw_input('')
    if line == '':
        break
    allLines.append(line)

fullInput = '\n'.join(allLines)
print('You entered this:')
print(fullInput)
```